# Is there a way to take a C# class or library and automatically convert it to Visio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visio

I have a C# class library that I need to document.  Is there a way I can convert the project or class to a Visio Uml.

I am using Visual Studios 2008 Professional.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this thread answers your question:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vstsarch/thread/07b39757-eac4-49fa-81d5-8d167c9b9d21/

*As mentioned by "Program.X" the above link no longer works.*

Short answer:  Reverse engineering of code in to Visio UML models works with the combination of Visio Pro 2007 and Visual Studio Team System for Software Architects 2005. It does not work with Visio Pro 2007 and Visual Studio Team System Architecture Edition 2008. However, Visio Pro 2007 does allow you to do reverse engineering of databases.

Why?:  The ability to reverse engineer code is now provided by all versions of Visual Studio in the form of the class designer where the code is continuously synchronized with model. Additional modeling functionality will be provided within Visual Studio Team System in the future.

Apparently someone found a workaround for VS2008 but use it at your own risk.
http://www.nullify.net/Article/298.aspx

There is also an MSDN article on the subject:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc947873.aspx